# Extending prototype function without overwriting it

Tags: javascript, prototype, parse-platform

I need to fix a bug in the `save` function of the Parse.Object library. However, when I try to call the original `save` function in my overwritten prototype, it loops recursively until the stack overflows!

```
Parse.Object.prototype.save = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    fixIncludedParseObjects(this);

    Parse.Object.prototype.save.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3); // endless loop
};
```

How can I change the endless loop line to call the original function made by parse?

Thanks!

Comment: I LOVE this question but still can't find an answer that works for me, even with the answer from @xdazz.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function(save) {
  Parse.Object.prototype.save = function (arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    fixIncludedParseObjects(this);
    save.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
  };
}(Parse.Object.prototype.save));
```

Comment: Can you please explain what's going on here? Or some link which does. Thanks

Comment: @Adnan You need to save the old save method to a variable, in this way, use the function parameter `save`.

Comment: I appreciate this answer but cannot figure out how to get it to work in this case where my original function (`Survey.SurveyPage.prototype.render`) has a bunch of references to `this`. Because I assume "this" changes. So I wonder how I can change my attempt of extending it here: `(function (originalFunction) { Survey.SurveyPage.prototype.render = function () { originalFunction.call(this);  }; }(Survey.SurveyPage.prototype.render));`

Comment: I found a blog post that pointed me in the right direction and inspired this, which seems to do what I was hoping for: `Survey.SurveyPage.prototype.render = (function (_super) {
            return function () {
                beforeSurveyPageRender();
                var origResult = _super.apply(this, arguments);
                afterSurveyPageRender();
                return origResult;
            };
        })(Survey.SurveyPage.prototype.render);//http://jondavidjohn.com/extend-javascript-functions/`

Comment: For those confused at the slightly bizarre-looking function wrapping going on here, this answer was written in 2012 when IIFEs were apparently all the rage.

See Below the Radar's answer for a more readable version, and this StackOverflow post explaining IIFEs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228308/

Answer (score 11):

Similar to accepted answer but maybe a little easier to understand

```
var originalSaveFn = Parse.Object.prototype.save;
Parse.Object.prototype.save = function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    fixIncludedParseObjects(this);
    originalSaveFn.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
};
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Parse.Object.prototype.save = function (save) {
    return function () {
        fixIncludedParseObjects(this);
        //Remember to return and .apply arguments when proxying
        return save.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(Parse.Object.prototype.save);
```

Comment: Works, but gives the JSHint error "Wrap an immediate function invocation in parentheses" https://jslinterrors.com/wrap-an-immediate-function-invocation-in-parentheses